# HandleFault in CXF interceptors

Tags: java, web-services, soap, error-handling, cxf

I'm using CXf's fault out interceptor to intercept the exception from the web services method. That works fine within the handleMessage method..
Now I have two questions,

1. How do I had extra information to the Fault object apart from setting the faultcode?

Say if there is any error in the handleMessage method, the control goes to handleFault method but in the handle fault method it simply unwinds and logs something like - GetMth has thrown exception, unwinding now: java.lang.Exception. But the fault message(in xml format) is not being sent to the client as Output mesasage,

  2. How do I make sure that the fault message is sent as SOAPfault to the clinet? (in the hanldeMessage below, i have place `f=null` to introduce the fault) Please Suggest!!!

I managed to write the xml content to the writer class with the below code, but am unable to pass this message to the client. I mean even after writing the message to the xmlwriter class and content being written fine to the console log, its not been sent to the client. i.e, I dont see the outbound message being sent nor printed when i turn on the monitors and the interceptor outbound logs. Could anyone please help me with this?

```
            MessageFactory factory = getFactory(message); 
            SOAPMessage soapMessage = factory.createMessage(); 
            SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart(); 
            SOAPBody soapBody = soapPart.getEnvelope().getBody();   
            SOAPFault soapFault = soapBody.addFault();   
            soapFault.setFaultString("Strange"); 
            W3CDOMStreamWriter writer1 = new SAAJStreamWriter(soapPart); 
            message.setContent(XMLStreamWriter.class, writer1); 
            message.setContent(SOAPMessage.class, soapMessage); 
            message.setContent(Node.class, soapMessage.getSOAPPart()); 
            message.getInterceptorChain().add(SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.INSTANCE);
```

LOGS:

```
saaj the factory com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_2.SOAPMessageFactory1_2Impl@146ee9c 
saaj the soapMessage  com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_2.Message1_2Impl@1db52c8 
saaj the soapPart  com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_2.SOAPPart1_2Impl@17d6c1 
saaj the soapsoapBodyPart  [env:Body: null] 
saaj the soapFault  [env:Fault: null] 
saaj the setFaultString  Strange 
saaj the messg  {org.apache.cxf.message.Message.RESPONSE_CODE=200, HTTP.RESPONSE=org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade@2982bf, org.apache.cxf.headers.Header.list=[], wrote.envelope.start=true, org.apache.cxf.message.Message.ENCODING=UTF-8, org.apache.cxf.message.FaultMode=CHECKED_APPLICATION_FAULT, org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapVersion=org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.Soap12@b16f5f, Content-Type=application/soap+xml, org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor.original.xml.writer=[StreamWriter: class com.ctc.wstx.sw.SimpleNsStreamWriter, underlying outputter: com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter@1144823], org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor.log-setup=true, org.apache.cxf.service.model.BindingFaultInfo=org.apache.cxf.service.model.BindingFaultInfo@106def2} 
saaj the writer1 :   
><pre><env:Header/><env:Body><env:Fault><env:Code><env:Value>env:Receiver</env:Value></env:Code><env:Reason><env:Text xml:lang="en-US">Strange</env:Text></env:Reason></env:Fault></env:Body>  </pre>
```

Please advise.

Comment: Can you share your WSDL?